# Solve for independent variable between data points in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, time-series, interpolation, nan, solver

I have many sets of data over the same time period, with a timestep of 300 seconds. Sets that terminate before the end of the observation period (here I've truncated it to 0 to 3000 seconds) have NaNs in the remaining spaces:

```
x = [0;300;600;900;1200;1500;1800;2100;2400;2700;3000];
y(:,1) = [4.65;3.67;2.92;2.39;2.02;1.67;1.36;1.07;NaN;NaN;NaN];
y(:,2) = [4.65;2.65;2.33;2.18;2.03;1.89;1.75;1.61;1.48;1.36;1.24];
y(:,3) = [4.65;2.73;1.99;1.49;1.05;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN];
```

[image: data plot]
I would like to know at what time each dataset would reach the point where y is equal to a specific value, in this case y = 2.5

I first tried finding the nearest y value to 2.5, and then using the associated time, but this isn't very accurate (the dots should all fall on the same horizontal line):

```
ybreak = 2.5;

for ii = 1:3
[~, index] = min(abs(y(:,ii)-ybreak)); 
yclosest(ii) = y(index,ii); 
xbreak(ii) = x(index);
end
```

[image: data with dots for the time at which y=2.5]

I then tried doing a linear interpolation between data points, and then solving for x at y=2.5, but wasn't able to make this work:

First I removed the NaNs (which it seems like there must be a simpler way of doing?):

```
for ii = 1:3 
    NaNs(:,ii) = isnan(y(:,ii));   
    for jj = 1:length(x);    
        if  NaNs(jj,ii) == 0;
            ycopy(jj,ii) = y(jj,ii);
        end
    end
end
```

Then tried fitting:

```
for ii = 1:3                    
f(ii) = fit(x(1:length(ycopy(:,ii))),ycopy(:,ii),'linearinterp');
end
```

And get the following error message:

```
Error using cfit/subsasgn (line 7)
Can't assign to an empty FIT.
```

When I try fitting outside the loop (for just one dataset), it works fine:

```
f = fit(x(1:length(ycopy(:,1))),ycopy(:,1),'linearinterp');

f = 

     Linear interpolant:
       f(x) = piecewise polynomial computed from p
     Coefficients:
       p = coefficient structure
```

[image: fitted curve for one dataset]

But I then still can't solve f(x)=2.5 to find the time at which y=2.5

```
syms x;
xbreak = solve(f(x) == 2.5,x);

Error using cfit/subsref>iParenthesesReference (line 45)
Cannot evaluate CFIT model for some reason.

Error in cfit/subsref (line 15)
        out = iParenthesesReference( obj, currsubs );
```

Any advice or thoughts on other approaches to this would be much appreciated. I need to be able to do it for many many datasets, all of which have different numbers of NaN values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mention `y=2.5` is not in your data set so the value of `x` which corresponds to this depends on the interpolation method you use. For linear interpolation, you could use something like the following

```
x = [0;300;600;900;1200;1500;1800;2100;2400;2700;3000];
y(:,1) = [4.65;3.67;2.92;2.39;2.02;1.67;1.36;1.07;NaN;NaN;NaN];
y(:,2) = [4.65;2.65;2.33;2.18;2.03;1.89;1.75;1.61;1.48;1.36;1.24];
y(:,3) = [4.65;2.73;1.99;1.49;1.05;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN];

N = size(y, 2);
x_interp = NaN(N, 1);
for i = 1:N
    idx = find(y(:,i) >= 2.5, 1, 'last');
    x_interp(i) = interp1(y(idx:idx+1, i), x(idx:idx+1), 2.5);
end

figure
hold on
plot(x, y)
scatter(x_interp, repmat(2.5, N, 1))
hold off
```

[image]

It's worth keeping in mind that the above code is assuming your data is monotonically decreasing (as your data is), but this solution could be adapted for monotonically increasing as well.